# Error (Cocoa error 3840) (Invalid value around character 0) on post with AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, json, afnetworking

I am using `AFNetworking` 2.0 to do API calls.

I am trying to post data to a web service by using method:

```
- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)POST:(NSString *)URLString
               parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
                  success:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject))success
                  failure:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error))failure
```

Post Dictionary:

```
{
    uid = "B6ACB3EF-3E95-4313-9BC2-6FB47808D938";
}
```

getting error as:

```
Exception: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 0.) UserInfo=0xd0d7a10 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}`
```

Thank you.

Comment: I think your server is sending a bad response (i.e. not JSON or whatever you are expecting at the client). Log the response.

Comment: @OMK, backtrace please.

Comment: @DavidCaunt you are right. This is due to bad response from server.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the response from the server. It may be sending a bad response. You can test it with Postman for Chrome or RESTClient for Firefox.